# Why does "git fetch" fail on HTTPS URLs with "Function is not available" on HP-UX?

Tags: git, curl, hp-ux

When I run `git fetch` I get the following:

```
$ git fetch
Password for 'xxx':
error: cannot create thread: Function is not available
fatal: cannot start thread to parse advertised refs
$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that this particular distribution of git/curl is lacking pthread. One way to fix it is to use `LD_PRELOAD`:

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/hpux32/libpthread.so git fetch
Password for 'xxx':
$
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, finally this problem was caused by `Cannot allocate memory`, low memory problem.

So Pls check it. Hope it helps.